# how to access footer & header in main file while footer & header have separate file i want to access these two file in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

file1.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import mysql.connector as mysql
import tkinter

root=tkinter.Tk()

root.title("headr")
root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")

Footer_Frame=Frame(root,bg="green")
Footer_Frame.place(x=0,y=550,height=150,width=1350)

root.mainloop()
```

file2.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import mysql.connector as mysql
import tkinter

root=tkinter.Tk()

root.title("headr")
root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")

Headrbtn_Frame=Frame(root,bg="green")
Headrbtn_Frame.place(x=0,y=0,height=150,width=1350)

prinfo=Button(Headrbtn_Frame,text="Profile info",width=10,font=("time new roman",15,"bold"))
prinfo.grid(padx=(830,0),row=0,column=0,pady=100)

pas=Button(Headrbtn_Frame,text="Change Password",width=20,font=("time new roman",15,"bold"))
pas.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=10)

login=Button(Headrbtn_Frame,text="LOG in",width=10,font=("time new roman",15,"bold"))
login.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

how to access in main file... plz help me i'm a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: What is `main` file? You need to clarify what you want us to do.

Comment: main file means access in 3rd file

Comment: how to access these two file in 3rd file

Answer (score 0):

You can't use these two files together. You should only ever create a single instance of `Tk`, and you should only ever call `mainloop` once. Each file is doing that, making them incompatible.

In order to use those two files in another file, you should rewrite them so that the code you want to reuse is inside a class or function. Then, you can import the class or function and use it like you would any other class or function.

For example, your "file 1" could be rewritten like this:

```
# file1.py
import tkinter as tk
def create_footer(master):
    Footer_Frame=tk.Frame(master,bg="green")
    Footer_Frame.place(x=0,y=550,height=150,width=1350)
    return Footer_Frame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tkinter.Tk()

    root.title("headr")
    root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
    ff = create_footer(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Then, in some other file you could use this like so:

```
from file1 import create_footer
...
ff = create_footer(root)
...
```

Even better would be to make `FooterFrame` a class that inherits from `Frame`, so you can use it like any other widget.

```
# file1.py
import tkinter as tk

class FooterFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        <other initialization code here>

# main.py
import tkinter as tk
from file1 import FooterFrame
root = tk.Tk()

ff = FooterFrame(root)
ff.place(...)
```

Comment: ff = Footer_Frame(root)
NameError: name 'Footer_Frame' is not defined

Comment: tnx dear, successfully fixed.